# Get img src of the closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My HTML is:-**

```
<div class="mb10">
    <input id="input-upload-img1" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" name="img1" accept='image/*,video/*'>
</div>
```

I'm using [FileInput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) JS library, which initializing a `file` input type adds more HTML to it.

**JQuery**

```
$("#input-upload-img1").fileinput();
```

After Initializing, it adds few HTML to it.

```
<div class="mb10">
    <span class="file-input file-input-new">
        <div class="file-preview "> <!-- This whole div is initially hidden, ie display:none-->
            <div class="close fileinput-remove text-right">×</div>
            <div class="file-preview-thumbnails"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="file-preview-status text-center text-success"></div>
            <div class="kv-fileinput-error file-error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group ">
            <div class="form-control file-caption kv-fileinput-caption" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="file-caption-name" style="width: 322.42px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default fileinput-remove fileinput-remove-button" type="button"><!-- This button is initially hidden, ie display:none-->
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                Remove
                </button>
                <div class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                    Browse …
                    <input id="input-upload-img1" class="file" type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" name="img1" data-preview-file-type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

After selecting an image, I get the following HTML:-

```
    <div class="mb10">
        <span class="file-input">
            <div class="file-preview">
                <div class="close fileinput-remove text-right">×</div>
                <div class="file-preview-thumbnails">
                    <div id="preview-1469278203925-0" class="file-preview-frame">
<!--Check added image.-->
                        <img class="file-preview-image" style="width:auto;height:160px;" alt="IMG_20160606_210238.jpg" title="IMG_20160606_210238.jpg" src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/27307c69-0599-4622-93f1-bf8ae6cc0e5c"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="file-preview-status text-center text-success"></div>
                <div class="kv-fileinput-error file-error-message" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group ">
                <div class="form-control file-caption kv-fileinput-caption" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="file-caption-name" style="width: 234.22px;" title="IMG_20160606_210238.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default fileinput-remove fileinput-remove-button" type="button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        Remove
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                            Browse …
                            <input id="input-upload-img1" class="file" type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" name="img1" data-preview-file-type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Note the added `img` tag.

Now, I'm writing a JQuery to get the `src` of the `img` tag upon selecting a file. How can I do it?

Here is my jQuery:-

```
$('.file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (!file){
        return
    }

    var source_image = $(this).closest('div .file-preview-frame').find('.file-preview-image')
    alert(source_image.attr('src'))
}
```

It returns **undefined**. I guess its because the dynamic adding of the image. How can I get the image source of the file selected.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think you've wrongly understood the usage of **[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**. It reads, *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the `DOM` tree*. You see, when change on `.file` element occurs, it traverses through its ancestors where in `span.file-input` will be one of the ancestors and `div.file-preview-frame` is not. So you should visit `span.file-input` and then find `div.file-preview-frame`.</strike>

You should be probably doing this.

```
$('.file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (!file){
        return
    }

    var source_image = $(this).closest('span.file-input')
                       .find('div.file-preview-frame .file-preview-image')
    alert(source_image.attr('src'))
}
```

---

**Update**

I went on to check the `plugin` and found few events like below which you can really use:

> **[`fileLoaded`](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileloaded)**:
>
> This event is triggered after a file is loaded in the preview.
>   Additional parameters available are:
>
> - **`file`**: the file object instance
> - **`previewId`**: the identifier for the preview file container
> - **`index`**: the zero-based sequential index of the loaded file in the preview list
> - **`reader`**: the FileReader instance if available.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> $('#input-id').on('fileloaded', function(event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
>     console.log("fileloaded");
> });
> ```

---

> **[`fileSelect`](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileselect)**
>
> This event is triggered after files are selected in the file input via
>   the file browse button. This is slightly different than the change
>   event in the sense that this will be triggered even if the file browse
>   dialog is cancelled.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $('#input-id').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
>     console.log("fileselect");
> });
> ```

I would prefer `fileLoaded` event which you can use as below:

```
$('.file').on('fileloaded', function(event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
  console.log(file);
  //file will have many details like lastModified, name, size, type etc.,
});
```

Comment: Still returns `undefined`.

Comment: Can it because of the dynamic generation of the elements?

Comment: No. Every attribute returns `undefined` even with `$(source_image).attr('attr_name');`

Comment: Is there any other thing that I can try giving a shot?

Comment: It returns an object. What shall I specifically see into?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118090/discussion-between-pythonenthusiast-and-guruprasad-rao).